# nineoldandroid AnimatorListener called multiple times

Tags: android, nineoldandroids

Hi I'm trying to do a series of animations but it's failing miserably. It worked fine when it was just 4.0 but I added support for 2.2 and 2.3 using nineoldandroid. it seamed to work but the `AnimatorListener`'s method `onAnimationEnd` is called twice.

This is the code I'm using for the animation:

```
animate(horizontalView)
   .translationX(xDelta)
   .setDuration(2000)
   .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
      //listener implementation onAnimationEnd
      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
         animate(droppingView)
              .translationY(yDelta)
              .setDuration(2000)
              .setListener(null)
              .start();
      }
   }).start();
```

The first animation fires its listener twice and the second animation 3 times. This only happens on 2.2 and 2.3 from what I've tested.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removing the old listener

```
animate(horizontalView)
   .translationX(xDelta)
   .setDuration(2000)
   .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
      //listener implementation onAnimationEnd
      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
         animator.removeListener(this); // << this
         animate(droppingView)
              .translationY(yDelta)
              .setDuration(2000)
              .setListener(null)
              .start();
      }
   }).start();
```

Comment: yes i've tried. apparenty the class `ViewPropertyAnimatorPreHC` used por older android class a different listener then that one. I had to save the instance of `animate(horizontalView)` and do `.setListener(null)`. what i can see that happend is that it fires the listener for each property animated... or something like that